# Intro to Python: Text Based Adventure

Tags: python

Good evening everyone,

I am currently enrolled in an intro to scripting class where my final project is creating a text based adventure game. Essentially the idea is to have a player move through rooms and collect items without encountering the villain. The issue that I am having is accessing the items from my rooms dictionary and then appending them to the inventory list that I created for the player. I have looked into several other examples, but I can't seem to find one that works for my game. I don't know if it would be best to create an entirely new function for collecting items and then try to incorporate decision branching that calls the function or if there is something simpler than that. I've attached my code below and would love to know where to start. Also if anyone sees anything else that they would change please let me know. Any help is appreciated.

```
def main_menu():
    #  Print the introduction and available player commands
    print("Oh joy...another mortal. Well, mortal, if you would like to return to your own world feel free to "
          "wander the Master's garden in search of an exit.")
    print("There are six unique items you will need to collect in order to return home. Oh! And mind the Mind Flayers.")
    print("They will take your sanity as surely as staying in this garden would. Good luck...")
    print()
    print("Move Commands: North, South, West, East")
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'Item'")
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")


def you_died():
    print('You reach the peaceful shores of the drowned lake and suddenly you'
          'feel an alien presence in your mind... It is too late to run, you are dead.')

def main():
    main_menu()
    # Create a dictionary to house the rooms and items
    rooms = {
        'Garden of Madness': {'name': 'Garden of Madness', 'South': 'Screaming Tombs', 'North': 'Bone Orchard',
                              'East': 'Dream Cells', 'West': 'Wraith Point', 'item': 'nothing'},
        'Screaming Tombs': {'name': 'Screaming Tombs', 'North': 'Garden of Madness', 'East': 'Ghost Raven Grotto',
                            'item': 'a Wooden Spoon'},
        'Ghost Raven Grotto': {'name': 'Ghost Raven Grotto', 'West': 'Screaming Tombs', 'item': 'Moldy Cheese'},
        'Bone Orchard': {'name': 'Bone Orchard', 'South': 'Garden of Madness', 'East': 'Cheerful Mausoleum', 'item':
                         'a Hand'},
        'Cheerful Mausoleum': {'name': 'Cheerful Mausoleum', 'West': 'Bone Orchard', 'item': 'a Book of Jokes'},
        'Dream Cells': {'name': 'Dream Cells', 'West': 'Garden of Madness', 'North': 'Soul Vineyard', 'item':
                        'a Pretty Crystal'},
        'Soul Vineyard': {'name': 'Soul Vineyard', 'South': 'Dream Cells', 'item': 'a Squirrel'},
        'Wraith Point': {'name': 'Wraith Point', 'East': 'Garden of Madness', 'North': 'Drowned Lake',
                         'item': 'nothing'},
        'Drowned Lake': {'name': 'Drowned Lake', 'item': 'the Mind Flayer!!'}  # Villain!!
    }

    # Establish how players current location will be called
    current_loc = rooms['Garden of Madness']

    # Establish the current commands available to the player
    commands = ['North', 'South', 'West', 'East', 'Item']

    # Create a blank list for the inventory
    inventory = []


    # Begin the game
    while True:
        print('You are in the {}.'.format(current_loc['name'], ))  # Print the player's current location
        print('This room contains {}.'.format(current_loc['item'], ))  # Print the item in the locations
        print('Your Inventory: {}'.format(inventory, ))  # Print the player's inventory

        command = input('\nWhat would you like to do?').strip()  # Get player command input
        if command in commands:

            if command in current_loc:
                current_loc = rooms[current_loc[command]]
                # FIXME game needs to call the you_died function and end the game in 'Drowned Lake'
            else:
                # Prompt user to choose a valid direction
                print('You run headlong into a wall and take a nasty bump on your head.'
                      'Please try a different direction.')

        elif command.lower() in 'quit':  # quit command valid for testing only
            print('You embrace the insanity within and skip gleefully into madness.')
            break
        else:
            # Print statement when invalid command is given
            print('The madness of this place must be getting to you. Please give a valid command.')
    print()


main()
```

Comment: Have you tried putting this on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)? This is more along their stride. StackOverflow is great for when you start getting errors.

Comment: Looks neat! Looks like you are on the right track. Your organization of the rooms and managing of the status look reasonable to me. I agree with @DavidCulbreth, the question is a little vague at the present. Can you narrow down a specific question or problem with your code? Otherwise the code review approach might be the way to go.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth & William, Code Review is for *already working* code. OP doesn't know how to write a working function for what they want, so this question would be inappropriate there.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your input and suggestions. I don’t know if my solution was the most elegant, but I basically stopped trying to append the inventory list and then remove the item from the dictionary. Instead I just added a loop in the get item function that iterated over the inventory list to check if a specific item existed in the list and if it didn’t then it would append to the list.

Answer (score 0):

this question is too vague as there is a lot this app will need to do.

It was quite a cool thing though and you've added some good code there, so here's my attempt at what I *think* you're trying to:

**Tested at [this sandbox](https://edube.org/sandbox)**

```
    #  Print the introduction and available player commands
    print("Oh joy...another mortal. Well, mortal, if you would like to return to your own world feel free to "
          "wander the Master's garden in search of an exit.")
    print("There are six unique items you will need to collect in order to return home. Oh! And mind the Mind Flayers.")
    print("They will take your sanity as surely as staying in this garden would. Good luck...")
    print()
    print("Move Commands: North, South, West, East")
    print("Add to Inventory: get 'Item'")
    print("-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")


def you_died():
    print('You reach the peaceful shores of the drowned lake and suddenly you'
          'feel an alien presence in your mind... It is too late to run, you are dead.')

def main():
    main_menu()
    # Create a dictionary to house the rooms and items
    rooms = {
        'Garden of Madness': {'name': 'Garden of Madness', 'South': 'Screaming Tombs', 'north': 'Bone Orchard',
                              'east': 'Dream Cells', 'west': 'Wraith Point', 'item': 'nothing'},
        'Screaming Tombs': {'name': 'Screaming Tombs', 'north': 'Garden of Madness', 'east': 'Ghost Raven Grotto',
                            'item': 'a Wooden Spoon'},
        'Ghost Raven Grotto': {'name': 'Ghost Raven Grotto', 'west': 'Screaming Tombs', 'item': 'Moldy Cheese'},
        'Bone Orchard': {'name': 'Bone Orchard', 'South': 'Garden of Madness', 'east': 'Cheerful Mausoleum', 'item':
                         'a Hand'},
        'Cheerful Mausoleum': {'name': 'Cheerful Mausoleum', 'west': 'Bone Orchard', 'item': 'a Book of Jokes'},
        'Dream Cells': {'name': 'Dream Cells', 'west': 'Garden of Madness', 'north': 'Soul Vineyard', 'item':
                        'a Pretty Crystal'},
        'Soul Vineyard': {'name': 'Soul Vineyard', 'South': 'Dream Cells', 'item': 'a Squirrel'},
        'Wraith Point': {'name': 'Wraith Point', 'east': 'Garden of Madness', 'north': 'Drowned Lake',
                         'item': 'nothing'},
        'Drowned Lake': {'name': 'Drowned Lake', 'item': 'the Mind Flayer!!'}  # Villain!!
    }

    # Establish how players current location will be called
    current_loc = rooms['Garden of Madness']

    # Establish the current commands available to the player
    commands = [['north', 'south', 'west', 'east'], ['item']]

    # Create a blank list for the inventory
    inventory = []

    test=True
    testCommands=["east","item"]
    testItter=0
    dead=False;
    # Begin the game
    while dead != True:
        print('You are in the {}.'.format(current_loc['name'], ))  # Print the player's current location
        print('This room contains {}.'.format(current_loc['item'], ))  # Print the item in the locations
        print('Your Inventory: {}'.format(inventory, ))  # Print the player's inventory
        if(test and testItter<len(testCommands)):
            command=testCommands[testItter]
            testItter=testItter+1
        else:
            command = input('\nWhat would you like to do?').strip()  # Get player command input
        if command.strip().lower() in commands[0]:

            if command in current_loc:
                print("You head : "+command+" leaving behind "+current_loc['item'])
                current_loc = rooms[current_loc[command]]
                if(current_loc ==rooms['Drowned Lake']):
                    dead=True;
                # FIXME game needs to cbeat mind flayer if you have all items
                # if len(inventory)>5:
            else:
                # Prompt user to choose a valid direction
                print('You run headlong into a wall and take a nasty bump on your head.'
                'Please try a different direction.')
        if(dead != True):
            if(command.strip().lower() in commands[1]):
                if command.lower().strip()  == "item" and current_loc['item'] !="nothing":
                    inventory.append(""+current_loc['item'])
                    current_loc['item'] = 'nothing'
               
                else:
                    # Print statement when invalid command is given
                    print('The madness of this place must be getting to you. Please give a valid command.')
        else:
            you_died();
        if command.lower() in 'quit':  # quit command valid for testing only
            print('You embrace the insanity within and skip gleefully into madness.')
            break
            
    print()


main()
```

Comment: Lol I collected a whole lot of squirrels :-) (item not removed from room on pickup)

Comment: @Chris lmao, fixed